# Java script not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android

Working With Android Different API levels have their different pros and cons. I am working with API level 10 and having an Issue .

In API level 10 java script methods are not getting evoked. Using `WebView`  in android is working fine with API level 11 and above but not working with below 11. Like following methods is not working in API level 10

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

but they are working fine in API level 11 and above. Is there any other method for below 11 or does it not supported in below API level 11.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in api lvl 10:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

should be okay in android 2.2, though...